# Hide keyboard when user taps anywhere else on the screen in android using BaseActivity

Tags: android, onclick, android-softkeyboard

I have attempted multiple answers on a question similar to this and have been having trouble, I'm a beginner. Right now I am trying this answer indicated in bold below: I am unfamiliar with what this person means by *creating a BaseActivity and writing global code.*
**I just found another approach if we don't want to give any EditText as input and want to hide keyboard inside whole application when user touches anywhere else other than EditText. Then you have to *create an BaseActivity and write global code for hiding keyboard as below,***

```java
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    boolean handleReturn = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    View view = getCurrentFocus();

     int x = (int) ev.getX();
     int y = (int) ev.getY();

     if(view instanceof EditText){
         View innerView = getCurrentFocus();

         if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && 
                                !getLocationOnScreen(innerView).contains(x, y)) {

             InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) 
                              getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindow().getCurrentFocus()
                                                             .getWindowToken(), 0);
         }
     }

    return handleReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I found this method from a stack overflow user and it works fine
>
> **Inside your activity**

setupUI(findViewById(R.id.activity_id), this);

> **Static helper class**

```
public static void setupUI(View view, final Activity activity) {

    // Set up touch listener for non-text box views to hide keyboard.
    if (!(view instanceof EditText)) {
        view.setOnTouchListener(new EditText.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(activity);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //If a layout container, iterate over children and seed recursion.
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            View innerView = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i);
            setupUI(innerView, activity);
        }
    }
}


private static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
            (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                    Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```